# Why do people like to pair CLEAR_TOP and SINGLE_TOP in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

The flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` finds the task containing activity X and clears the top to bring X to its resume state. The flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, would only keep a single instance of X at the top. Therefore, I should never need to include `SINGLE_TOP` if I am already using `CLEAR_TOP`: that's because `CLEAR_TOP`'s behavior includes `SINGLE_TOP`'s behavior. So why do so many sample codes include the two together? Is it because those developers don't understand the full power of `CLEAR_TOP`? Again, almost every example I see online includes the two together. Why the redundancy?

For example if I call `CLEAR_TOP` for X on the task `W->X->Y->Z`, then I get `W->X`. On the other hand, if I were to call SINGLE_TOP for X on the task `W->X->Y->Z` I would end up with `W->X->Y->Z->X` and if I were to call it for Z I would get `W->X->Y->Z`. So really `CLEAR_TOP` adds nothing to the equation: it's like adding 0 to some other value.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The behaviour of `CLEAR_TOP` is different, depending on whether or not the Activity is a `singleTop` activity or the flag `SINGLE_TOP` is also provided.

Let's first assume that the Activity has a standard launch mode (not `singleTop`). If you use the `CLEAR_TOP` flag without `SINGLE_TOP`, Android does the following:

- Clears the Activity stack back to (**and including**) the target Activity (by finishing all activities in the stack that were on top of target activity and finishing the existing instance of the target activity).
- Creates a **new instance** of the target Activity and calls `onCreate()` on that instance.

Instead, let's assume that the Activity still has a standard launch mode (not `singleTop`). If you use the `CLEAR_TOP` flag **together with** the `SINGLE_TOP` flag, Android does the following:

- Clears the Activity stack back to (**but NOT including**) the target Activity (by finishing all activities in the stack that were on top of the target activity).
- Calls `onNewIntent()` on the existing instance of the target Activity, passing the `Intent` that was used in the `startActivity()` call.

As you can see, the behaviour is different.

NOTE: If the target Activity is declared as `launchMode="singleTop"` in the manifest, then the behaviour of using `CLEAR_TOP` should be the same as if you also specified `SINGLE_TOP`. However, there are some bugs in Android related to this (I can't find the links at the moment). So you shouldn't rely on the `launchMode` setting, but always specify `SINGLE_TOP` flag if you want the existing instance of the target Activity NOT to be recreated.

Comment: I humbly accept your explanation because it is accurate (I am able to verify it). However most sample code I see online just pair the two flags without understanding that they have to take `onNewIntent()` into consideration so as to get the new intent instead of the original intent that comes with `getIntent()`. Many thanks for your reply.